# Runtime error in line 25: Char 35: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct HASH_TABLE' (solution.c)

Tags: c, hashtable

```
#define SIZE 50

typedef struct{
    int key;
    int value;
}HASH_TABLE;

HASH_TABLE* hashArray[SIZE];

int hashCode(int key) {
   return key % SIZE;
}

bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize){

    int count = 1,i=0;

    HASH_TABLE* data  = (HASH_TABLE*)malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE*));
    data->value = count;

    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        int hashIndex = hashCode(nums[i]);
        hashArray[hashIndex]->key = nums[i];
        hashArray[hashIndex]->value = data->value;

        ++hashIndex;
        hashIndex %= SIZE;

        if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == nums[i])
        {
            data->value++;
        }



    }
    if(data->value>0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to code for finding duplicates using hash table algorithm in C.

The code should work in following ways

Given an array of integers, find if the array contains any duplicates.

Your function should return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and it should return false if every element is distinct.

Example 1:

Input: [1,2,3,1]
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: [1,2,3,4]
Output: false
Example 3:

Input: [1,1,1,3,3,4,3,2,4,2]
Output: true

please help me resolving my error

Thank you

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE*))` → `malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE))`

Comment: You have allocated memory for a pointer to some struct, not memory for one struct.

Comment: It is very difficult to see which is your error, if you only post a snippet of code (not a complete example) and you don't say what is the expected (and not seen) output of your execution.  Please edit your post to state these two things and use the minimum code to show a complete run. Just a snippet and your interpretation of what is happening (which is normally wrong) is always of no use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

- You have given space for only one value for each hash entry in the table.  This means you are comparing the numbers by their hash value only and not by their integer value.  Let's say you enter `1` and later on you have `51`.  Both have the same hash value, as you compute the remainder modulo `50` as the hash value, so they will go in the same table entry (the entry with index `1`), this is the second entry.  When you read the number `51`, you change the value in the field `data` to `51`, and, if later on, arrives another `1`, you'll end losing it as the first `1` you had before,  just flied out when you added the `51` number.  The hash table allows you to get faster access, but you have to store all the keys you can have, despite of the hash value they have.  So each table entry must support a list of entries all with hash value x, and the list must have all the entries that share the same hash, and compare the individual keys to see which one is the one you are comparing.
- You should use `malloc(sizeof *data)` or `malloc(sizeof(HASHTABLE))`, better than what you do.  In your code you allocate bytes to hold a pointer (you specify the size of a pointer, not the size of a record).  `sizeof *data` is the size of the pointed to data (yes, you can use it after a `sizeof` operator, even if it has not been allocated yet, the compiler is not interested in the value pointed, just in the data size of it)
- Never, never never, cast the value returned from `malloc(3)`.  This is not what you want.  It allows you to forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` (where a proper prototype of `malloc(3)` is given) and so, hide further errors, and this is far more dangerous than the error you want to avoid.  Malloc always returns a pointer, but if you don't use a prototype (and this happens if you have casted the value returned and forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>`, the compiler will assume `malloc()` returns an `int` (which is not true) and will generate code to convert the value returned into a pointer to `HASH_TABLE`, and this will trash the data returned by `malloc()` in the best case.  In a 64bit architecture, pointers are 64bit, while integers are only 32.  In this architecture the value returned by malloc is 64 bit wide... the compiler will generate code to convert the 32 bits of a (undefined behaviour) 32 bit data, and convert it (extending with undefined behaviour) that data to 64bit, and making a pointer with (undefined behaviour) that data.  You'll most probably receive a segmentation fault and a program crash, when you try to use your pointer for anything else than printing its value.
- if you are using so simple hash function, then you had better to use a prime number for the number of elements in the hash table, so you'll not get some entries crowded of data, while others are empty.  Using a prime number allows for better distribution of numbers (although it is better to select a better hash table function)